# Windows Firewall: Inbound rule. Randomly generated program path

Tags: wildcard, windows-firewall, inbound, inbound-security-rule, firewall-rules

I am creating and Inbound firewall rule to allow a program. Problem is, program path is slightly different on each system.

Path is as follows

C:\windows\users\%username%\appdata\local\apps\2.0\yh786.y7u\gui65gd.7uy\Program.exe

C:\windows\users\%username%\appdata\local\apps\2.0\hy87h.t5r\hytd43.6tf\Program.exe

On every system the two directories between  \2.0\ AND \program.exe are different and randomly generated.

When I am making the inbound rule is there a wildcard I can use in the program path for these randomly generated segments.

Comment: Why does the path differ?

Comment: @Slbox I'm not actually sure. \2.0\ and it's contents are created during the installation process but all instances use the program.exe

Comment: How is the program installed?

Comment: @Slbox by running the installation  application provided.  The issues I'm facing is not with the install. It's with the firewall rule and how to get around makinging 100 individual rules for these randomly generated portions